# Tag exception to notify caller to utilize the exception message

Tags: java, exception

I have a library doing some parsing logic of requests. In some cases I would like to provide some hint messages with my exceptions to the caller.

Is there a way to tag/flag the exception I throw to the caller that the error message is useful? The caller will be able to check that tag/flag and knows that the information comes with the exception is useful and utilize it. For other exception without the tag, the caller will ignore the exception messages.

Comment: you can use Listener to notify the

Comment: try customizing a wrapper to wrap exception.